# Parsing Wildberries. Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver

I parse items from [Wildberries](https://www.wildberries.ru/). Unfortinately when I am trying to load a page I cannot gey a content of the page (only menu)

I have tried to do it by means of selenium, but the situation is not better:

```
url = 'https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/detyam/odezhda/dlya-devochek/dzhinsy-dzhegginsy'
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options=opts)
driver.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
container = text.find_all('div', class_='product-card__wrapper') #Here should be a container of items of a page but now I cannot get a content
```

Are there any other ways of maybe some setting for driver to get a content?

Comment: you can try `from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait` and specify which element to wait for

Comment: but it's better to learn queries and work with json, as an [example](https://catalog.wb.ru/catalog/children_girls/catalog?appType=1&couponsGeo=12,3,18,15,21&curr=rub&dest=-1029256,-102269,-1278703,-1255563&emp=0&kind=3;5&lang=ru&locale=ru&page=1&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=0&regions=68,64,83,4,38,80,33,70,82,86,75,30,69,22,66,31,48,1,40,71&sort=popular&spp=0&stores=117673,122258,122259,125238,125239,125240,6159,507,3158,117501,120602,120762,6158,121709,124731,159402,2737,130744,117986,1733,686,132043&subject=180;1687)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am starting to learn queries. If you haven/t deleted the part of code that you wrote to get this example could you please share it with me. It will realy help me to undestand the topic better

Comment: I didn't write the code, just looking in the developer tools (f12 chrome -> network tab) and found this query which gives the required information